# Finding the second smallest number using loops in python

Tags: python, loops, function

I was wondering how to find the **second smallest number** from a user-input list with def functions. Also, **WITHOUT** using any sorting functions, imported modules, and min() and max() functions, how would I find the numbers by using just loops and relational operators?

Here's my following code (I only have finding the smallest number so far...):

```
def second_smallest():
    smallest = second_smallest[0]
    for i in second_smallest[1:]:
        if smallest > i:
            smallest = i
    return smallest
```

Examples of following tests are shown:

```
print(second_smallest([5, 7, 2, 1, 3]))
2
print(second_smallest([100, 51, 31, 5, 10]))
10
```

Thanks!

Comment: `second_smallest` is both a function and a list? I guess you need to edit your code sample in the question.

Comment: Yes. That will cause some problems for you.

Comment: What is the expected output of `print(second_smallest([-1, 1, 2, 3, 0, -1]))`. Is it `-1` or `0`?

Comment: For people who find this who aren't asking SO to do their homework, the correct answer is: [`heapq.nsmallest(2, mylist)[1]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) (Note: This will raise an `IndexError` if the list in question is less than two elements long, handling that would be dependent on desired behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> def second_smallest(lst):
...     first = second = float("inf")
...     for num in lst:
...         if num < first:
...             second, first = first, num
...         elif first < num < second:
...             second = num
...     return second
```

Please note that this returns `float('inf')` *(initial value)* for lists with `len(lst) <= 1` as there is no second item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

SO Isn't really for homework, but it sounds like you have had a think about this. There are two situations to consider and both require knowledge of the smallest:

1. the second smallest is seen **before** the smallest is seen, in which case the second smallest will be the value that smallest held before it held its final value.
2. The second smallest is seen **after** the smallest is seen, in which case the second smallest will be bigger than it, but smallest won't be smaller than it OR equal to it

I've expressed this in the code below. We've had to keep the existing smallest tracking and add to it.

```
def second_smallest():
    smallest = float("inf")
    second_smallest = float("inf")
    for i in second_smallest:
        if smallest > i:
            second_smallest = smallest
            smallest = i
        elif second_smallest > i and not smallest == i:
            second_smallest = i
    return second_smallest
```

Note, technically there might not be a second smallest, if you provide a list of the same numbers. e.g. `[4,4,4,4]`. The code above will return 4, but really, it's an error case that should be considered and dealt with.

This is a simple approach that would break down for a question like "what is the nth smallest?" At which point you have basically created a sorting algorithm.

Comment: You should be looping over `smallest[2:]`.

Comment: not sure about that!

Comment: Nevermind, your updated logic is more complex but takes care of it.

Comment: indeed, editors, voters and commenters were fast off the mark ;)

Comment: Also, you could scale this pretty easily by using a list to retain the n smallest elements.

Comment: Well then you've implemented a sorting algorithm of sorts, but used more memory

Comment: Thank you for the response! Though the code listed does not seem to pass a sequence of positive numbers such as [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Any suggestions?

Comment: whoops, that's an error in the starting conditions. edited and now identical to ozgur's answer