# Python - Get second smallest number without using array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print the second smallest number without using any array but it doesn't work. This is what I've done so far.

```
numbers = 5
print('Enter your numbers\n')

for x in range(0, numbers):
    use = input('Enter #' + str(x + 1) + ': ')
    if x == 0:
        small = int(use)
        second = small
    if int(use) < small:
        small = int(use)
        if small > second:
            second = int(use)

print('\nSecond smallest number is ' + str(second))
```

Comment: I will solve it. It takes some time.  Just wait

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Find second smallest number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779618/python-find-second-smallest-number)

Comment: @Ank No they are using array and other stuff. I needed logic not library. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works without lists and for number in any order.

```
numbers = 5
print('Enter your numbers\n')
#Instead of using lists, we'll use variables to store the smallest numbers. We'll give them the initial value of 0.
smallest = 0
secondsmallest = 0
    
for x in range(0, numbers):
    #We get the user input and convert it to int.
    use = int(input('Enter #' + str(x + 1) + ': '))
    #If the smallest variable hasn't been touched, i.e., it's the first time the for loop is run, we assign the current input to be the smallest number.
    if smallest == 0:
        smallest = use
    #Else if the current input is smaller than the current smallest number, then it should be the new smallest number.
    elif use < smallest:
        smallest = use
    #Else if the current input is greater than the smallest and the secondsmallest number still is untouched then the current input should be the secondsmallest.
    elif use > smallest and secondsmallest == 0:
        secondsmallest = use
    #Else if the current input is less than the secondsmallest, then it should be the new secondsmallest.
    elif use < secondsmallest:
        secondsmallest = use
        
print(secondsmallest)
```

Comment: I haven’t tested your code, but if it works then this is what I was actually looking for. Without using any array/list/libraries or other python only solutions.

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
numbers = 5
min = 2**32
second_min = 2**32
print('Enter your numbers\n')

for x in range(numbers):
    use = input('Enter #' + str(x + 1) + ': ')
    if int(use) < min:
        min = int(use)
    elif int(use) >= min and int(use) < second_min:
        second_min = int(use)

print('\nSecond smallest number is ' + str(second_min))
```

result:

```
Enter your numbers

Enter #1: 5
Enter #2: 6
Enter #3: 7
Enter #4: 8
Enter #5: 9

Second smallest number is 6
```

Comment: What if the inputs are greater than `2^32` ?  Python can handle large integers also.

Comment: @Ank it just a default min value,if you need a huge input, can change it easily.

Comment: This is a bit more complex but it’s interesting. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = 5
print('Enter your numbers\n')

small = float('inf')
second = float('inf')

for x in range(0, numbers):
    use = int(input('Enter #' + str(x + 1) + ': '))
    if use < small:
       small = use
    if use > small and use < second:
        second = use

print('\nSecond smallest number is ' + str(second))
```

P.S. float('inf') is most biggest number

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
nums = [1, 2, 9, 11, 13]
for counter,num in enumerate(nums):
 
    if counter == 0:
        smallest = num
    if counter == 1:
        second = num
    if counter > 1:
        if second == smallest:
            second = num
        if num < second:
            second = num
        if second < smallest:
            smallest, second = second, smallest
                     
print(second)
```

Here is the algorithm of my approach :

1. First initialise the smallest and second smallest numbers to be the first two inputs. That is, `Smallest=First_Input` and `second_smallest = Second_Input`. These lines do that:

```
    if counter == 0:
        smallest = num
    if counter == 1:
        second = num
```

2. Next See the third number. If the third number is smaller than the `second_smallest` number, then swap them. These lines do that

```
    # This part is executed only when the counter exceeds 1
    # That is, from the third input onwards.
    if num < second:
        second = num
```

3. Now See the `smallest` and `second_smallest` number. If `second_smallest < smallest` , then swap them. These lines do that:

```
    if second < smallest:
        smallest, second = second, smallest
```

4. Now, there will be an edgecase for inputs `[smallest, smallest, x, y, z]` . That is, when smallest number is repeated. It is because, the `smallest` and `second` variables store the first smallest and second smallest numbers respectively. But when the smallest number is repeated, they both store the same value(i.e the `smallest` value). Therefore in this case, the actual `second_smallest` value will not be able to replace the value in `second`(since `second` stores the smallest in this case)
   To fix this, We have this line of code :

```
     if second == smallest:
         second = num
```

Answer (score 0):

We can solve the problem by using another one temp variable.
Let's assume to input one variable - v.
**First**, compare v with the smallest number.
If v is smaller than the smallest number, the smallest number will be v and the second small number will be a previous smallest number.
**Second**, if v is equal or bigger than the smallest number, compare with the second small number and handle it.

```
import sys
numbers = 5
second = sys.maxsize
smallest = sys.maxsize

for x in range(0, numbers):
    use = int(input('Enter #' + str(x + 1) + ': '))
    if use < smallest:
      second = smallest
      smallest = use
    elif use < second:
      second = use

print('\nSecond smallest number is ' + str(second))
```