# Max Margin of List python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that finds the maximum integer of a list, and the margin between the highest number and the second highest number. I want it to return these tuple values:

```
    >>>max_margin([5,6,4,3])
    (6, 1)

    >>>max_margin([8, -2, 8, -3])
    (8, 0)

    >>>maxmargin([2])
    (2, None)

    >>>maxmargin([])
    (None, None)
```

I have made code which accomplishes this, but It's not the best way to go about it. Here it is:

```
    def max_margin(int_list):

        if not int_list:
            return None, None

        else:
            maxnum = nextval = int_list[0]
            bymargin = None

            for i in intlist:

                if i > nextval:
                    nextval = i

                if i > maxnum:
                    tmp = nextval
                    nextval = maxnum
                    maxnum = tmp

                    bymargin = maxnum - nextval

                if maxnum == i and nextval == i:
                    maxnum = i
                    nextval = i
                    bymargin = maxnum - nextval

                if len(int_list) <= 1:
                    maxnum = maxnum
                    bymargin = None

        return maxnum, bymargin
```

Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on CodeReview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can remove the first `else` and thus save an indentation level

Comment: @VincentSavard any ideas how to actually mark the question as off-topic? It seems to only allow the 5 most common sites for migration, so I wasn't sure what best to do (I agree, this should be on codereview).

Comment: @dwanderson: As far as I know, it's not possible to migrate it ourselves and we need a moderator to do it.

Comment: Yeah, but we can't even appropriately mark *where* it should be migrated, because it only allows 5 pre-determined sites. So, marking as off-topic now feels confusing. Probably a quesiton for (or already on) meta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this, int_list2 is not needed if you don't care about what happens to int_list.

```
def max_margin(int_list):
    if len(int_list)==0:
        return None,None
    if len(int_list)==1:  
        return int_list[0],None  
    max_val = max(int_list)
    int_list2 = list(int_list)
    int_list2.remove(max_val)
    max_val2 = max(int_list2)
    return max_val,max_val-max_val2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the list first to make it easy.

```
In [1]: def max_margin(int_list):
   ...:     args = sorted(int_list)
   ...:     try:
   ...:         return (args[-1], args[-1] - args[-2])
   ...:     except IndexError:
   ...:         try:
   ...:             return (args[-1], None)
   ...:         except IndexError:
   ...:             return (None, None)
   ...:         

In [2]: maxmargin([5,6,4,3])
Out[2]: (6, 1)

In [3]: maxmargin([8, -2, 8, -3])
Out[3]: (8, 0)

In [5]: maxmargin([2])
Out[5]: (2, None)

In [6]: maxmargin([])
Out[6]: (None, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

A rather straightforward `O(Nlog(N))` solution could involve just sorting the list.

```
def maxmargin(my_list):
    largest, secondlargest = sorted(my_list,reverse=True)[:2]
    return largest, largest - secondlargest
```

Else if runtime is of great importance you could have an `O(N)` solution by iterating only once, like so *(credit to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16226255/4686625) for inspiration for second largest)*

```
def max_margin(my_list):
    count = 0
    largest = second_largest = float('-inf')
    for x in my_list:
        count += 1
        if x > second_largest:
            if x >= largest:
                largest, second_largest = x, largest
            else:
                second_largest = x
    return largest, largest - second_largest if count >= 2 else None
```