# Find the second largest number in a list of numbers using python3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I know there are [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225677/get-the-second-largest-number-in-a-list-in-linear-time) to this question, but the problem I am having with my code is that it works for most occasions except when it prints out the max number. As long as the first two numbers or more in the list are the max. It may sound confusing, but here's my code with an example.

```
def s_max(l):
    pos = 0
    m1 = max(l)
    m2 = 0
    for i in l:
        pos += 1
        if i > m2 and i != m1:
            m2 = i
        elif m2 == 0 and i == m1 and pos > 1:
            m2 = m1
        elif i < m1 and i <= m2:
            i = m2
        else:
            m2 = m2
    print(m2)

s_max([10,10,9])

OUTPUT = 10
```

When I use a list of numbers such as [9,10,10], the code will output 9.

Comment: what should be the output for this list `[9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 11]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this:

```
def s_max(l):
    while 1:
        val=max(l)
        l.remove(val)
        if val not in l: break
    return max(l)
output=s_max([10,10,9])
print(output) #prints 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You may create a generic function to get the `n`th largest number via creating a function using [**`sorted()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) with [**`set()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) as:

```
def get_n_largest(num_list, n):
    return sorted(set(num_list))[-n]
```

Sample run:

```
>>> get_n_largest([9,10,10], 2)
9
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first iteration of the `for` loop just before the `if-else` block is executed your variables have following values:

```
m1 = 10
m2 = 0
i = 10
pos = 1
```

This means that the final `else` branch gets executed and since it sets `m2=m2` nothing changes.

On the second iteration before `if-else` values are the same **except** that `pos = 2`. Now this causes the second branch to execute:

```
elif m2 == 0 and i == m1 and pos > 1:
    m2 = m1
```

There you set `m2` to maximum you already found. On the third iteration third branch in `if-else` block get executed which changes nothing since you just assign value to loop variable.

All in all your code fails in case that two first values are the maximum items on the list. With minimal modifications you could just set the `m2` if `i` is greater than current `m2` but less than maximum value:

```
def s_max(l):
    m1 = max(l)
    m2 = 0
    for i in l:
        if m2 < i < m1:
            m2 = i

    print(m2)
```

If you don't want to write your own function you can use [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
>>> import heapq
>>> l = [10, 10, 9]
>>> heapq.nlargest(2, set(l))[1]
9
```

Note that above assumes that there are two unique values on your list.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the second largest number by sorting

```
>>> l = [1, 9, 8, 5, 2, 1, 7]
>>> second_largest_number = sorted(l)[-2]
>>> print(second_largest_number)
Output: 8
```

You can use below function without using sorting

```
def f(l):
  a = l[0]
  b = l[0]
  for i in l:
    if i > a and i > b:
       b = a
       a = i
    elif i > b:
       b = i
    elif b == a:
       b = i
  return b

>>> l = [1, 9, 8, 5, 2, 1, 7]
>>> f(l)
Output: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Way did not use just sorted and set :

```
l=[9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12, 11]
sorted(set(l))[-2]
```

Output :

```
11
```