# I am finding the second largest number from the array list, but I get runtime-error when the input arr is 6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,5

Tags: python, runtime-error, runtime

when i compiled this program in VSCode, I got IndexError. Is there any other solution?

```
#here is my sample code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
    x = len(arr)
    arr.sort()
    for i in range(0, x-1):
        #removing redundant values
        if arr[i] == max(arr):
            arr.remove(arr[i])

    arr.remove(max(arr))
    print(max(arr))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the second largest number in a list in linear time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225677/get-the-second-largest-number-in-a-list-in-linear-time)

Answer (score 0):

split using `split(',')` when input is `6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,5`

`arr = list(map(int, input().split(',')))`

Comment: If you look closely OP implements `.remove()` while iterating over the array, which explains the IndexError

Comment: the split function is working perfectly fine, the error is in the for loop.

Comment: @Rahul You're right. What to do in order to overcome this issue?

Comment: @YashPatel I've linked an answer in the comments, here you go again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Comment: @YashPatel wont `sorted(array)[-2]` is you solution, then why writing for loop

Comment: @Rahul using split in this manner itself is giving error plus his logic is wrong

Comment: @prashantrana I don't think OP meant to actually give input as `6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,5`, it was just the way OP typed it into the question, yes his logic is wrong too. This has 2 questions in itself due to ambiguity.

Comment: @Rahul he mentioned that input is given this way, read question

Comment: @prashantrana That is what I'm trying to say, by guessing his program I don't think OP meant to give input that way, I'm just saying he typed it that way into the question, as I said it has 2 questions in itself due to ambiguity. Since he lists IndexError and not something else.

Comment: @prashantrana The program is working for other inputs. But when there are more similar values, the loop removes those elements and IndexError occurs. Can you guys give me a solution regarding my issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're not updating the length after the first iteration you will end up, thinking you have a bigger array than you do, as you remove them all. Resulting in an IndexError.

If you make a copy of the array you can always iterate over that allowing you to edit the original list meanwhile.

Comment: Hey, can you explain to me in detail how I can do this?