# find second largest number from list using for loop with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

when I run the code, it returns 9 but the answer should be 10

```
       list = [9, 6, 4, 10, 13, 2, 3, 5]
        max = list[0]
        second_last = list[0]
        for x in list:
            if x > max:
                max = x
            # Here is an issue with this statement 
            if x > second_last and x != max:
                second_last = x
        print(second_last)
```

Comment: Don't use `list` and `max` as names for your own variables. You overwrite the built-ins ([`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list), [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)) with the same name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the second largest number in a list in linear time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225677/get-the-second-largest-number-in-a-list-in-linear-time)

Answer (score 2):

Once you have a new max, just push the old max down to the second max

```
list = [9, 6, 4, 10, 13, 2, 3, 5]
max = float('-inf')
second_last = float('-inf')
for x in list:
    if x > max:
        second_last = max
        max = x
    elif x > second_last and x != max:
        second_last = x

print(second_last)
```

Comment: For `lst = [9, 15, 13]` it returns a wrong answer.

Comment: good point, corrected it

Comment: right, Now its should return true answer

Comment: but don't have a need to change list variables to float('-inf') , thanks for sharing answer

Comment: You have to in case the first element is the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
l = [9, 6, 4, 10, 13, 2, 3, 5]

_max = max(l)
_second = min(l)

for num in l:
    if _second < num < _max:
        _second = num
            
print(_second)
```

Comment: Could also use `if _second < num < _max:`.

Comment: That chained comparison is btw probably not just shorter/clearer, but also faster. Because `_max > num` is very likely true, causing two comparisons most of the time, while `_second < num` is very likely false, so if you test that first, most of the time you need just one comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
x:      max and second_last
9:      9 and 9
6:      9 and 9
4:      9 and 9
10:     10 and 9
13:     13 and 9 <<<
2:      13 and 9
3:      13 and 9
5:      13 and 9
```

You are essentially losing information about `second_last`, which is held by `max` until it is replaced by `x` when `x > max`. Whenever `max` is updated, technically `second_last` should also be updated, as the old `max` is the new `second_last`.

Notice that if the first `if` statement is satisfied, the second **cannot** be satisfied, so `max` and `second_last` are never updated simultaneously.

So, unless there is some value `y` further down in the iteration such that `second_last < y != max` - Eg: `list = [9, 12, 10]`, `y = 10` -, your code will produce incorrect outputs. So, your code never updates `second_last` when the sequence is strictly increasing.

Here is a fix for your code:

```py
list = [9, 6, 4, 10, 13, 2, 3, 5]
max = list[0]
second_last = list[0]
for x in list:
    if x > max:
        second_last = max # add this line
        max = x 
    elif x > second_last and x != max:
        second_last = x
print(second_last)
```

Besides, it is a good idea, not to assume the list is non-empty.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer,  you have put the right answer and explain the whole code in detail

Answer (score 0):

```py
list = [9, 6, 4, 10, 13, 2, 3, 5]
max = list[0]
second_last = list[0]
for x in list[1:]:
    if x > max:
        second_last = max
        max = x
    elif x < max and x > second_last:
        second_last = x
print(second_last)
```

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer with an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You could build a new list containing 2 elements (`max` and `second_last`):

```
lst = [9, 6, 4, 10, 13, 2, 3, 5]
# results[0] = max; results[1] = second_last
results = [float("-inf"), float("-inf")] # initialise negative infinite!

for item in lst:
    if item > results[0]:
        results = [item, results[0]]

print(results)
# OR
max_value, second_last = results
print(max_value)
print(second_last)
```

Out:

```
[13, 10]
13
10
```

Easiest approach would be using built-in sort:

```
results = sorted(lst, reverse=True)
print(results[:2])
>>> [13, 10]
```

Node: `list` and `max` are Python built-ins, do not use them as variable names.

Comment: Fails the same input as the other answer.